# Address of local variable returned--can ignore warning without detriment but what's the proper way?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, scope

I have a class `Particle`:

```
class Particle {
private:
    float x, y, z;
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    float* getPos() {
        float p[3] = {x, y, z};
        return p;
    }
    // ...
};
```

I would call this method like:

```
Particle a = Particle();
// ...
float* pos = a.getPos();
```

And then reference the position elements with `pos[0]` through `pos[2]`.

g++ spouts warning message as stated in the title. But the functionality is exactly how I want it: returning an array. Why does the warning exist and is there a "proper" way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: If local variable isn't static - you'll get undefined behavior, and quite likely a crash in runtime. Either return instance created by new operator(and don't forget to free the memory via delete), also you can use std::unique_ptr for it... Or just return by value

Comment: Return a copy of the array instead. Consider using `std::array<float, 3>`.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a chunk of memory. That chunk of memory has to be allocated, data has to be copied into it, and then at some point after the pointer is finished being used, the block of memory has to be freed. How are you expecting the block of memory to be freed and how are you expecting it to be determined when it can be freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd skip `std::array`/`std::vector` here, because in your particular case, the position of each value imposes independent meaning. In general, sequence types have ordering, `tuple`s have structure; if the element count is fixed (and often heterogeneous) and sorting (or otherwise reordering the values) is intrinsically nonsensical (e.g. in the case of a coordinate, swapping the `x` and `y` values changes the *meaning*), then a `tuple` makes more sense.

In this case, you could just declare:

```
std::tuple<float, float, float> getPos() {
    // C++17 or higher allows list initialization
    return {x, y, z};

    // Pre-C++17 you use the std::make_tuple helper
    return std::make_tuple(x, y, z);
}
```

The advantage here is that you can then unpack the result in the caller easily, either with `std::tie`:

```
float x, y, z;

std::tie(x, y, z) = a.getPos();
```

or on C++17 or higher with structured bindings, it's even nicer, since you can declare and initialize the variables with `auto`, rather than declaring with explicit types, then reassigning with `tie`:

```
auto [x, y, z] = a.getPos();
```

You can store the `tuple` itself and use `std::get` if you prefer, but unpacking to useful names rather than obscure `std::get` indices usually makes for much cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a C-array like that, return `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<float, 3> getPos() {
    std::array<float, 3> p = {x, y, z};
    return p;
}
```

You'll need to include `<array>` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning an array. It's impossible to return an array in C++. You're returning a pointer to an array which no longer exists. Hence the warning.

You could make the array a part of your class and return a pointer to that. In general I wouldn't call that good design

```
class Particle {
private:
    float pos[3];
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    float* getPos() {
        return pos;
    }
    // ...
};
```

You could return a `vector<float>` instead. You could return an `array<float,3>` instead. You could ask yourself why you need this.

Answer (score 0):

`p[3]` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope so you shouldn't return a pointer to it.
Either return a `std::array<float, 3>` by value or consider making a class for positions too, and return a Position object, or a reference to it. Example:

```
struct Position {
    float x, y, z;
};

class Particle {
private:
    Position m_pos;
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    Position const& getPos() const { return m_pos; }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: If I were pedantic I'd say that `p[3]` never existed in the first place ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you're function is indicative of poor design. Provide [getter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) methods an allow the user of your class to access member variables:

```
class Particle {
private:
    float x, y, z;
public:
    float GetX() const { return x; }
    float GetY() const { return y; }
    float GetZ() const { return z; }
};
```

Given `const Particle a` this will let you initialize an array as follows: `const float pos[] = { a.GetX(), a.GetY(), a.GetZ() }`

Creating a `Particle` method to allow the user to populate a `float[]` will encourage the user toward one of the following bad practices:

1. `float* Particle::GetPos() const { return new[3]{ x, y, z }; }` creates dynamic memory without clearly informing the caller that the memory needs to be released
2. `array<float, 3U> Particle::GetPos() const { return { x, y, z }; }` requires the allocation and creation of a temporary to populate a `float[]`
3. `void Particle::GetPos(float* param) const { param[0] = x; param[1] = y; param[2] = z; }` misses the opportunity for constant arrays and incurs potential caller misuse, as it's not clear that `param` must have room for at least 3 `float`s